# What does the "segmentation fault: 11" mean? How to fix?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, matplotlib, tkinter

I wanted to plot some data that gets updated overtime using Tkinter. Before started coding, I thought that the code might already be on Google... and it is, of course. I found an easy example-code on Quora, but when I run it (from the Terminal), the Tkinter window closes and the terminal shows 'Segmentation fault: 11'. What does this mean and how to fix it? I have MacOS 10.14.2.

I have already searched for the bug, but I cannot find it. The code is the one that I found on Quora with minor changes that I made while I was looking for the bug. The complete code from Quora can be found on:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-a-real-time-plot-with-matplotlib-and-Tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import time
import threading

continuePlotting = False

def change_state():
    # Pause or resume live plot

    global continuePlotting

    if continuePlotting == True:
        continuePlotting = False
    else:
        continuePlotting = True

def data_points():
    f = open('data.txt', 'w')
    for i in range(10):
        f.write(str(randint(0,10)) + '\n')
    f.close()

    f = open('data.txt', 'r')
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    l = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        l.append(data[i])
    return l

def app():

    root = Tk()
    root.config(background='white')
    root.geometry('1000x700')

    lab = Label(root, text='Live Plotting', bg='white').pack()

    fig = Figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
    ax.grid()


    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

    def plotter():
        while continuePlotting:
            ax.cla()
            ax.grid()

            dpts = data_points()

            ax.plot(range(10), dpts, marker='o', color='orange')
            graph.draw()
            time.sleep(1)

    def gui_handler():
        change_state()
        threading.Thread(target=plotter).start()

    b = Button(root, text='Start/stop', command=gui_handler)
    b.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app()
```

Comment: I think the restriction that tkinter is not thread-safe still stands. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/26161635/4545530 . All the plotting in the code you posted does not happen in the thread where the Tk instance was created and as such is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

As tkinter is not thread-safe, you better use `.after()` instead of threading.  Rewrite `plotter()` and `gui_handler()` as below:

```
def plotter():
    if continuePlotting:
        ax.cla()
        ax.grid()
        dpts = data_points()
        ax.plot(range(10), dpts, marker='o', color='orange')
        graph.draw()
        root.after(1000, plotter)

def gui_handler():
    change_state()
    plotter()
```